# DateTime Picker using edittext on Navigation Drawer not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, datetimepicker

I am new in programming and I would like to know if is it possible to add a date and time picker dialog on the navigation drawer since when I try to do it, it does not open the pop out. I will be including my code here which I copied from Youtube tutorials. I hope someone could help me

activity_date_time_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/date_time_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:editable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="SELECT DATE and Time"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:linksClickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

DateTimeDialog.java

```
package com.example.petmx;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateTimeDialog extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText date_time_in;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_date_time_dialog);

        date_time_in=findViewById(R.id.date_time_input);

        date_time_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDateTimeDialog(date_time_in);
            }
        });
    }

    private void showDateTimeDialog(final EditText date_time_in) {
        final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);

                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);

                        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-dd-YYYY HH:mm");

                        date_time_in.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
                    }
                };

                new TimePickerDialog(DateTimeDialog.this,timeSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false).show();
            }
        };

        new DatePickerDialog(DateTimeDialog.this,dateSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

    }

    private void showTimeDialog(final EditText time_in) {
        final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                time_in.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
            }
        };

        new TimePickerDialog(DateTimeDialog.this,timeSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false).show();
    }

    private void showDateDialog(final EditText date_in) {
        final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-dd-YYYY");
                date_in.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

            }
        };

        new DatePickerDialog(DateTimeDialog.this,dateSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }

}
```

drawer_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <group
        android:id="@+id/menu_top">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_spinner"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_heart"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/navi_spinner_menu"
            android:title="" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_datepick"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/activity_date_time_dialog"
            android:title="" />

    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/bottom">
        <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:title="Account Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
            android:title="Logout" />

    </group>


</menu>
```

mainNavigation.java

```
package com.example.petmx;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class mainNavigation extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    MenuItem menuItem;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    EditText date_time_in;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_navigation);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open,R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        //to change
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_fragment, new NavigationFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.date_time_input){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DateTimeDialog.class));
            finish();
        }

        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.home){
            //to change
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new NavigationFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.settings){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new Navigation2Fragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.logout){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            //FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been out in android programming but seems you're lacking the flag in the `Intent`. You might want to try the approach below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DateTimeDialog.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

The snippet above will start a new activity task. See this link:
[FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Comment: thank you for this, but still doesn't trigger the date and time dialog :(

Comment: Maybe you can try this implementation I found over the internet:
https://www.journaldev.com/9976/android-date-time-picker-dialog